# Memory Error in machine learning image processing

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, machine-learning

I am building an image processing classifier and this a small part of my code, my problem is 1st line indicates that I have a integer array `img_data_list`.  I am converting this to float, but this is giving me a `Memory Error`.

I have a data set of 7 Gb and 12 Gb of RAM.

```
img_data = np.array(img_data_list)
img_data = img_data.astype('float32')
img_data /= 255
print (img_data.shape)
```

Comment: See if using `np.divide(..out = img_data)` helps. Docs - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.divide.html. You can use `np.asarray(img_data_list)` to avoid making a copy there, but I guess that float conversion is making a copy anyway. So, just to combine : `np.asarray(img_data_list).astype('float32')`.

Comment: Think you should follow the links and search for the other funcs docs that I have stated. They have much more info than I can compile here.

Comment: a note for Divakar np.asarray(img_data_list).astype('float32') is not working for me can you please give me another solution

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any other solution.

Comment: okay thank you for your help 
can you please tell me what if I dont convert numpy array into float type I want know why we do this ?

Comment: Well, we are dividing by 255, because I guess we are normalizing of some sort. It all depends on how you intend to post process the data on whether you can optimize on the memory.

Comment: n note for @Divakar I am making a image processing classifier in which i have 66 classes so what do you think how many images do i need per class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you confused?  You have a 7G data set.  Your code demands three copies: the original data set, the NumPy array, and a float conversion of *that*.  You don't have enough memory to make even that second copy.

The obvious solution is to put more RAM on your machine; the configuration you have is not sufficient for the problem class you're trying to solve.  Another possibility is to convert your data to `float32` upon input, so that there's only one copy of the data ever in RAM.

Comment: any suggestions how can i avoid this

Comment: a note for prune I am making a image processing classifier in which i have 66 classes so what do you think how many images do i need per class

Comment: (1) That's a separate question. (2) That's more suited to the statistics group; (3) That's not enough information to make a recommendation -- it depends on the complexity of the images, their differences and similarities, and the complexity of the model.

Comment: The ultimate question here is whether the data set you have yields the accuracy you need.  I suggest that you reduce the data set and run it in batches that *do* fit into RAM.  If necessary, reduce this to single-image batches.

Comment: and one more thing I want to ask that I am also building text processing classifier and with the same scenario my question is how should I prepare my dataset for each class any suggestions

Comment: (1) That's a separate question; it gets a separate posting altogether.  (2) Your question is too general; the problem is highly dependen ton factors you haven't specified.  (3) You need to do your research before you ask here: there are many previous questions, as well as deep learning discussion, that deal with input preparation.

Comment: a note for prune

Comment: I am building a text classifier my question is (how to check the word is in vocabulary) I have created bag of words